# Passing state between pages?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation

I have a Silverlight Windows Phone 7 app with two pages. I want to pass some nontrivial state (an array or structs) between them. Do I have to follow a Web model where everything needs to be packed into query string? Makes little sense when all pages and classes are on the same device, within the same process and assembly.

So the questions are:
 - upon navigation between pages, is there a good way to pass data as-is?
 - upon page navigation, does code-behind of the source page have access to the code-behind of the destination page (or vice versa)?
 - is there any shared user object that all pages can refer to (like an ASP session)?

Alternatively, is there a way to nest XAML's? I could make do with a model where there's a outer container page that loads different content pages into a panel on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use the query string as you suggested. This makes sense from a web development perspective, but we aren't in a web development perspective.
2. Use a static variable. This is probably the simplest. Just declare another class with a static property, and you can share data this way. The only concern with this approach is thread-safety.
3. Use Isolated Storage.

Comment: I guess I'll go with option 2... but this is so unelegant. Why do we have to live with Web-inspired design constraints on a completely undistributed platform? Gross.

Comment: You can mask the ugliness if you want by using an IoC container and resolving it as a Singleton. That way you have a dependency you can fake out in needed.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to pass everything in a query string. Just pass an id and store the data non-trivial data in isolated storage between pages.

There is a series of articles on how to to do this [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage)

Comment: But that's persistent, isn't it? I was thinking - in memory.

Comment: It is. There is an in-memory store that I can't remember the name of, but by storing it in the isostore you cover yourself for tombstoning - when the app is taken out of memory when the start button is pressed or a phone call comes in.