# How can I pass object to another page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing state between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609091/passing-state-between-pages)

I went through lots of tutorials but still struggling of passing an object from one page to the other in Windows Phone7 Application.

it is simply can pass a primitive data with the query string. but I need to pass, for example a Student Object from page1 to Page2

Can anyone help me to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Every time someone prefaces a title with a tag I kill a kitten.  Apparently I'll have to go back to the pound and stock up today.

Comment: Here's an example of the same question and it's answer. (Hint: don't use isolated storage.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089758/reading-a-variable-set-on-another-page

Answer (score 1):

You could create some sort of a wrapper around the Navigate calls that takes your object as a parameter and saves it in a static/singleton public property, so when your navigation completes - you can retrieve that object, but if you want your code to work after tombstoning - you would also need to handle saving that object in isolated storage or having a way to reconstruct it otherwise.